# Show Toolbar on other activity Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-toolbar

I used default navigation drawer of android Studio - created project with Navigation Drawer Activity present on Android Studio. 
Now **i want to show Toolbar on other Activity too.**
i tried almost everything to get toolbar on main Acitivity but it through `NullpointerExpection`

**MainActivity.java**

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.show_navigation);


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Repalce with custom message ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

here is code of Naviagtion Drawer layout

**activity_navigation_drawer.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation_drawer" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_navigation_drawer.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.clint19.ecommerce_project.NavigationDrawer">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_navigation_drawer" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

here is Activity Layout where i want to get Toolbar 
**activity_main.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_product" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_product.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Help me out to show Toolbar on activity_main.xml layout**

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use Fragments, instead of Activities?

Comment: i did not work on Fragments that's why i m using activity@gprathour

Comment: Then you must start working on Fragments (at least if you want to have navigation drawer in your app)

Comment: i already created my app in activity need to show toolbar (NavigationDrawer ) only, Please Help , really needed. @gprathour

Comment: Ashu in this case, you should create only one activity which has Navigation Drawer and then for other screens you should create Fragments and show them in the same activity having Navigation Drawer. You should not put Navigation Drawer on all activities.

Comment: @AshuKumar you need to use fragment for this.

Comment: @gprathour do you have any example that have acitvity + framgment having  navigation Drawer, Plase give link

Comment: @AmitVaghela do you have any example, if yes, then please post link, i will go through that link

Comment: @AshuKumar try to use this example https://github.com/andreasschrade/android-design-template

Comment: library sdk api version support should be 4+ and i my ap uses api version 10 , i canot go with that @MohitSuthar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions

1. For this just ***create a BaseActivity class that implements the drawer***, and let all your ***other activities extend this one***. This is using **Activity**
2. If you want a navigation drawer, you should ***use fragments***. follow this tutorial and it works. Using **Fragments**

check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for fragment tutorial

Comment: i m reading first link , what is differece between both method @Amit Vaghela

Comment: i m on the way, too close to solve my Problem, i m follwing second option  as it is easy for me :), i was lokking for it since three days   @Amit Vaghela

Comment: i already accepted your answer, ca u please help me to get menu on navigation drawer, as it is not showing on navigation drawer  @Amit Vaghela

Comment: where have you stuck ? @Ashu Kumar

Comment: optionMenu is not showing on Navigation Drawer i have called `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` both, but it does not show :( @Amit Vaghela

Comment: okay. i need to see code to resolve it instead i suggest you to download code and then try again from link i have describe in answer.

Comment: your link is not working anymore, better you could add the code here.

Comment: @HussainKMRBehestee better you check updated answer and its a developer android official link. so it will allways works